# Torn Tallis Gadol

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, tallit-gadol

See the picture below.

The light blue represents the entire tallis gadol. The dark blue is where the corners are. Next to the bottom left corner there is a piece of the tallis gadol (represented by the white part) that is completely missing.

Can one still wear this tallis and make a bracha?
If it can't be worn if one would put a piece of cloth to fix it would it be a problem of "t'aseh v'lo min ha'asui"?

[image: square with dark blue in the 4 corners representing tzitzis; there is a missing section of beged to the right of the bottom-left corner]

Comment: I'm a little surprised that within 7 hours of asking this, not even one comment!

Comment: I personally don't understand the question and don't even know where to begin commenting.

Comment: @SethJ fair enough. The question is can someone wear such a tallis and make a bracha?

Comment: This seems too localized to me. What is it about this that makes you think you can't wear it, and how will this question help anyone else?

Comment: @SethJ  The question is if the corner is still "shayach" to the beged and can be called a "corner" if though it's missing. How will this question help anyone else? Like any question would that the answer can help understand better what the dinim are when a beged is torn b'clal and b'frat in this particular case.

Comment: If the Tallis had a tear in the middle, on a fold (very common) is it still fit for use?

Answer (score 2):

1) Your tallis seems to have more than 4 corners. But this is not a problem as long as the tiztizis are on the [four corners furthest apart – see Halacha 3](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/936343/jewish/Chapter-Three.htm.)

2) This [article](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=4&cat=7&newsletter=1087&article=4108) explains that “ta’aseh v’lo min he’asuy” means that something, like tzitzit, which the Torah says to make, has to be turned into a halachic entity by a direct action, not created by an indirectly created situation.

But in your example according to point (1) the tallis was kosher to start with and adding the patch does not make it any more kosher so it seems that there is not a problem of “ta’aseh v’lo min he’asuy”.

CYLOR

Update following DoubleAA's analysis. If his analysis is correct, then the tallis will be posul and adding the patch **will** constitute “ta’aseh v’lo min he’asuy”.

Comment: If this tallis really has a din of a 6 cornered tallis shouldn't the fourth corner (which is farthers apart) be the one on the bottom-right of the bottom-left dark-blue square? (I hope that location is clear.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Can you prove that geometrically please? If you change from the bottom left to the bottom-right of the bottom-left dark-blue square, it seems that you reduce the distance between the the two bottom dark-blue squares?

Comment: You do reduce that distance but you increase the distance between the two left dark-blue squares. So as long as the distance of the whole bottom side is 1 dark-blue-square-length longer than the distance of the whole left side then the farthest corner from both is the right corner of the bottom left dark-blue corner.

Comment: (This is assuming you take distance between corners as the crow flies and not along the edge of the tallis, in which case it would better to move to the bottom right corner of the bottom left dark blue square even in a square tallis because the length of the bottom side is increased by 2 dark-blue-square-side lengths by the hole.)